# How do you output Ruby on Rails console database resultsets in a pretty format without installing a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting data returned from running a database query like `User.first` but because there are so many fields it is hard to read the information.  I tried using `pp User.first` but it didn't make anything easier to read.  Is there something built-in to RoR where I don't have to install a gem that prettifies it? Also, I don't want to write an each statement to break it down each time if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like pp's output, I'm not sure what other options you have.  If you can get over not wanting a gem, Hirb does this nicely...

https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb